# Accessing/Filling PHP array from both partent and child classes

Tags: php

Given the following code I'd like to add strings to the array *ssmlArray* via addToOutput method. The problem I'm facing (please correct me if I'm wrong) seems to be when calling `$devclass->world();` the parent constructor get also called, resets *ssmlArray* and the only element within the array is "World".

```
$dev=new DevController;
$dev->index();

class DevController{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->ssmlArray=array();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->addToOutput("Hello ",false);
        $devclass=new ChildClass;
        $devclass->world();
    }
    public function addToOutput($ssml,$sendToOutput){
        array_push($this->ssmlArray,$ssml);
        if($sendToOutput==true){
            $ssml="";
            foreach($this->ssmlArray as $singlerow){
                $ssml.=$singlerow;
            }
            print_r(json_encode($ssml));
            exit;
        }
    }
}

#Childclass
class ChildClass extends DevController{
    public function world(){
        $this->addToOutput("world",true);
    }
}
```

I want to output the entire array as a string at once (only once print_r) and it needs to be fillable from child classes without clearing the contents. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `ChildClass`, it calls the parent's `__construct` if it doesn't have its own `__construct`. Therefore, `$ssmlArray` is created again. You can convert it to static variable.

Check it:

```
<?php
$dev=new DevController;
$dev->index();

class DevController{
    protected static $ssmlArray = [];
    
    public function __construct(){
        
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->addToOutput("Hello ",false);
        $devclass=new ChildClass;
        $devclass->world();
    }
    public function addToOutput($ssml,$sendToOutput){
        array_push(self::$ssmlArray,$ssml);
        if($sendToOutput==true){
            $ssml="";
            foreach(self::$ssmlArray as $singlerow){
                $ssml.=$singlerow;
            }
            print_r(json_encode($ssml));
            exit;
        }
    }
}

#Childclass
class ChildClass extends DevController{
    /*public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }*/

    public function world(){
        $this->addToOutput("world",true);
    }
}
?>
```

Demo: https://paiza.io/projects/ZQtGPvPYi8mxNqoitHqS8A

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!